# NSScrollView always appears on top of other views

Tags: cocoa, rubymotion

No matter what, it seems that my NSScrollViews always appear on top of any other view, even if the other view has been added more recently and should appear on top.

What can I do to get another view (say just a plain NSView) to appear above an NSScrollView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by setting `setWantsLayer` to `YES` (`true` in this case since I'm using RubyMotion) on the NSScrollView, the NSScrollView's content view and the external view that I want to appear above the NSScrollView.

That solved my problem and allowed other views to appear above the NSScrollView.

Answer (score -1):

So check your xib, and make sure your scrollview is at the topmost of your view hierarchy ("Document Outline").  However, when loaded this doesn't necessarily 100% guarantee that the scrollview will be drawn first.  A way to manually force the order you'd like for your views is to programmatically move them around based off tags.

In Interface Builder, in the Attributes Inspector, go to the bottom and find the "View" section.  Add a tag to the view, with 0 being the bottom most view you'd like, and going up from there.

Then in your controller, add this method definition & a call to it:

```
NSComparisonResult compareViews(id firstView, id secondView, void *context) {
   NSInteger firstTag = [firstView tag];
   NSInteger secondTag = [secondView tag];

   if (firstTag == secondTag) {
      return NSOrderedSame;
   } else {
      if (firstTag < secondTag) {
         return NSOrderedAscending;
      } else {
         return NSOrderedDescending;
      }
   }
}

[self.view sortSubviewsUsingFunction:(NSComparisonResult (*)(id, id, void*))compareViews context:nil];
```

This will ensure that you have your views in the correct order you'd like